# How to get the value of each item in the list and keep the structure of the list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to get the value of each item in the following list and keep the structure of the list, get the result `{{{9.99878}, -49.3753, 20.1}, {{9.99853}, -49.3137}, 10.2}`, what should I do?

```
Map[Values, {{{a -> 9.99878}, -49.3753, 
   b -> 20.1}, {{a -> 9.99853}, -49.3137}, c -> 10.2}, 1]
```

Then map the function f to each item in the list and keep the structure of the list, and get the result `{{{f[9.99878]}, f[-49.3753], f[20.1]}, {{f[9.99853]}, f[-49.3137]}, f[10.2]}`. How to achieve the above requirements.

```
Map[f, {{{9.99878}, -49.3753, 20.1}, {{9.99853}, -49.3137}, 10.2}, -1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following:

```
lstTemp = Map[Values, {{{a -> 9.99878}, -49.3753, b -> 20.1}, {{a -> 9.99853}, -49.3137}, c -> 10.2}, {-2}]
(* {{{9.99878}, -49.3753, 20.1}, {{9.99853}, -49.3137}, 10.2} *)
```

Then:

```
Map[f, lstTemp, {-1}]
(* {{{f[9.99878]}, f[-49.3753], f[20.1]}, {{f[9.99853]}, f[-49.3137]}, f[10.2]} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{a -> 9.99878}, -49.3753, b -> 20.1}, {{a -> 9.99853}, -49.3137}, c -> 10.2};
```

Using `CopyListStructure`

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[list, Cases[list, x_?NumberQ :> f[x], -1]]
```

{{{f[9.99878]}, f[-49.3753], f[20.1]}, {{f[9.99853]}, f[-49.3137]},
f[10.2]}

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{a -> 9.99878}, -49.3753, b -> 20.1}, {{a -> 9.99853}, -49.3137}, c -> 10.2};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. r_Rule :> Values@r

(*{{{9.99878}, -49.3753, 20.1}, {{9.99853}, -49.3137}, 10.2}*)

list /. {n_?NumericQ :> f@n, r_Rule :> f@Values@r}

(*{{{f[9.99878]}, f[-49.3753], f[20.1]}, {{f[9.99853]}, f[-49.3137]}, f[10.2]}*)
```